# Add rows dynamically hainf html helper in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Following is my code which i am using to add new row with the html helpers in each `td`.

I am making a view of Bill Of Material in my application for which I need to have a structure where there are many children(ingredients) under a main parent(Main Material).

My approach is to have html helpers in the td and with the button click add row and add the children(ingredients).

I am not able to get a new row when i click the button in my following code. Please help and please suggest if there is any other proper approach for getting my Bill Of Material view done.

I am taking reference of [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/bMyGY/1/) .

```
$("#myButton").click(function () {
    debugger;
    // Create elements dynamically
    var newRow = "<tr><td>'@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Id, new { @Value = "1" })'</td><td>'@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @Value = "Abcd" })'</td></tr>";
    alert(newRow);
    // Add the new dynamic row after the last row
    $('#aliasTable tr:last').after(newRow);
});


<h2>Index</h2>

<table id="aliasTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Id, new { @Value = "1" })
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Name, new { @Value = "Abcd" })
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button id="myButton">Add New Row</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change your code like below.

Note: The important thing is you need to mention the razer code (Html helpers) in between the single quotation like ('@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Id') .

If you must need the strongly type means please use the below code.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ActionMethodName()
{
    Test testData = new Test();
    testData.Id = 1 // if Id is integet else testData.Id = "1"
    testData.Name = "Abcd"
    return View("ViewName", testData);
}
```

You need to add the values from your action method only. then the value return to your page automatically.

Then you can use the below code in your java script to return the value.

```
var newRow = "<tr><td>" + '@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Id)' + "</td><td>" + '@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)' + "</td></tr>";
```

else if you don't need the strongly type means use the below code

```
var newRow = '<tr><td><input type="text" value ="1" name ="Id" /><input type="text" value ="1" name ="Name" /></td></tr>';
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error when I copy pasted your code. Syntax error and still no new row is added.

Comment: Now the error is gone but still I am not able to get a new row.

Comment: Please check the value getting in newRow variable by alert and make sure the $('#aliasTable tr:last').after(newRow);  is that the correct code to append new rows.

Comment: You can see my edit where I have provided a link which I am referencing.

Comment: Sorry for the delay ,I check and run the code, from that i get we cant able to assign the vale from html helper. if you try the updated code now it will works i checked it already

Comment: can you post the edited code. Because I have edited the same in my question but still it is not working.

Comment: Instead of using @Html.TextBox did you use the <input > tags.   That is what i used in hear. Please use the <input> tag as i given. refresh the page and you can able to see the code which i have update now and i checked it it works perfect. Please refresh  the page and copy paste the code. thanks.

Comment: No I did not. As I want a strongly typed model, so I need to have the @html.TextBoxFor

Comment: If you must need to use the strongly typed model. Just wait 2 mins I will update the that code. For that i need your Action method code.

Comment: Please update your action method code. Then only i can able show you how to use it.

Comment: as of now I dont have any action method I will be writing the Post action method but before that if the view works as I want then Only i will write the post method for the same. Still I have get view which is only having the return View() line in it.